# Does Multi-Fractal analysis on time series signal help extracting local properties?

Tags: fractals, fractal-analysis

Fractal based measures help quantify the self-similar geometrical properties of set (in this case a time-series signal). It mostly represents the global characteristics of geometry of the signal.
But with time series as data, we tend to look for local characteristics where Multi-Fractal Analysis is adopted.

If my understanding is right about Multi-Fractal Analysis, what are Multi-Fractal Analysis methods available and can be adopted?